# Find command giving error: "Run-time Error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set"

Tags: string, excel, vba, find

Trying to activate the cell in my column A which says "Generator loading".

I have been trying the 'With' and 'End With' commands and other suggested formats posted on the net. However, I keep getting the same error- Run-time Error 91.

From my various trials I am very sure that there is something wrong within the "Find" command, but I cannot figure out what... I have been filling it using the format on the MSDN page.

Do you have any suggestions?

```
Dim findstring As String
findstring = "Generator loading"

Sheets("Summary").Columns(1).Find(What:=findstring, After:=Cells(9,1)).Activate
```

Comment: That error comes up because one of the following is Nothing: Sheets("Summary") or Sheets("Summary").Columns(1). Try to assign each of that expressions to a variable checking their value.

e.g. Set summary = Sheets("Summary")

Comment: This code runs fine for me.  What "With" condition are you using? On which line of your code do you get this error?  Perhaps need to post all the offending code?

Comment: The error also arises if the result of the `.Find` method is `Nothing`, because you can't do `Nothing.Activate` @AlessandroCabutto

Comment: And actually @AlessandroCabutto, if `Sheets("Summary")` doesn't exist, then you get a type 9 Subscript out of Range error. `Columns(1)` exists on ALL *worksheet* objects, so if OP gets a 91 error, it is because the `Find` method has returned `Nothing`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error commonly arises if the result of the `.Find` method is `Nothing`, because you can't do `Nothing.Activate`

First, you have to check for *Nothingness*

```
Dim rng as Range
Set rng = Sheets("Summary").Columns(1).Find(What:=findstring, After:=Cells(9,1))

If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox findString & " not found!!", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

rng.Activate

'the rest of your code goes here...
```

Comment: Checked for nothingness with your message box and it couldn't find it. I tried finding a letter "A" which I put in one of the cells in column A and it found it => nothingness confirmed.

Finally I realised that in the sheet "Generator loading" was written with two spaces!! Initially I didn't want to run the wildcard commands because I have similar cells throughout column A. Now that I have spotted the problem I will lock the cell.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score -1):

I don't like to work with columns, so instead of it, I used a range.
For me to work, I just replaced the reference of the sheet

```
Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Find(What:=findstring, After:=Cells(9, 1)).Activate
```

See if this works. If not, you could send me the sheet if you want :)

Comment: This won't work if `findString` doesn't exist in the range. Also, this error has nothing to do with the sheet index (by name or by index), nor the way the range is defined (`Range("A:A")` vs. `Columns(1)`).

Comment: As Zemens said, the error was not concerned with the definition of the sheet or the range. I ruled these causes out when I tried specifying them using the 'With' command or defining them in variables. Thanks for the input though.