# Error 91 when using Cells.Find with window hidden

Tags: vba, excel

Please read this fully and understand that this program was working fine until I changed the way I was hiding the workbook.

I have a program that worked great while I was using `Application.Visible = False` and only showing the user form. I came to realize that this would hide all Excel windows and not just the one I was using. This is going to be distributed throughout the department and hiding all Excel windows was unacceptable.

I started using `ActiveWindow.Visible = False`, but I am now getting Error 91 anytime I search a worksheet for a value (`Cells.Find`).

Modifying the worksheet is not an option and the value for which I'm searching can move around the sheet depending on what has been added or removed.

`Cells.Find` worked out great for this reason. I need to either find another way to search the page, or find another way to hide the worksheet. Please help

Comment: It might help to see the exact code that's throwing the error, and to actually phrase a question. You have described a problem, not asked a specific question.

Comment: I [think](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264506(v=vs.60).aspx) that means a variable wasn't set - as @Mat'sMug mentioned, can you please post your code? Then, let us know what line throws the error.  AFAIK the visibility of a window shouldn't really affect VBA being able to find a value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26653203/find-command-giving-error-run-time-error-91-object-variable-or-with-block-v/26654386#26654386

Comment: $100 on @DavidZemens's link

Comment: The line I have not yet found a work around for is `CAddress = Cells.Find(Name).AddressLocal(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)`. but throughout the program I have run into this when Cells.Find has been used regardless of the context around it while the window is hidden.

Comment: There you go. Read the link provided by David. When `Find` doesn't find anything, it returns `Nothing`. You can't call `.AddressLocal` on `Nothing`.

Comment: This error happens when the value you're searching for via `Find` doesn't exist/can't be found.

Comment: so why is it working when the window.visible is true?

Comment: hrmmmm. it would help ifyou post the rest of your code, or at least the minimum amount needed to reproduce the error so that the rest of us don't have to reinvent the wheel...

Comment: When the window is not visible, the `Cells` reference is not qualified to a worksheet object (unless qualified, `Cells` refers to `ActiveSheet.Cells` and there is no `ActiveSheet`), so you can do like `Sheets("sheetname").Cells.Find` modifying "sheetname" as needed. May also need to qualify to a workbook, e.g., `Workbooks("workbookname").Sheets("sheetname").Cells.Find(...`

Comment: But still it is a good idea to test the result of `Find` before invoking additional methods on the range object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the window is not visible, the `Cells` reference is not qualified to a worksheet object (unless qualified, `Cells` refers to `ActiveSheet.Cells` and there is no `ActiveSheet`), so you can do like:

```
Sheets("sheetname").Cells.Find ' modifying "sheetname" as needed
```

This may also fail (with the same error), or it could also yield incorrect results if there are *other* open workbooks, so it's best to qualify to a workbook fully, e.g.:

```
Workbooks("workbookname").Sheets("sheetname").Cells.Find(...
```

It is still a good idea to test the result of `Find` before performing additional method/property calls against an object which *could* be `Nothing`, as per this answer:

[Find command giving error: "Run-time Error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26653203/find-command-giving-error-run-time-error-91-object-variable-or-with-block-v/26654386#26654386)

Comment: Nice, another good reason to qualify `Cells` and `Range` calls.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems to be working when I specify the workbook and sheet. Unfortunately, I have a lot of lines to go through to make these changes and I did this quite a lot. Looks like I'll be working late tonight. Full release is tomorrow.