# VBA: Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: vba

I'm trying to locate a range that below a string cell then copy that range to another sheet.
I'm succeed to locate and copy the range but cannot paste it to the another sheet due to that error 91 occurred. I've tried so many different ways but still the problem. Pls help me. Here are the code:

```
Sub Copy()

    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Dim FindRow1 As Range
    Dim FindRow2 As Range
    Dim FindRow3 As Range
    Dim a1 As Long
    Dim a2 As Long
    Dim b1 As Long
    Dim b2 As Long
    Dim c1 As Long

    Set SearchRange = Range("A1", Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
    Set FindRow1 = SearchRange.Find("EUR", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set FindRow2 = SearchRange.Find("USD", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set FindRow3 = SearchRange.Find("VND", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

    a1 = FindRow1.Row + 1
    a2 = FindRow2.Row - 1
    b1 = FindRow2.Row + 1
    b2 = FindRow3.Row - 1
    c1 = FindRow3.Row + 1

    Range(Cells(a1, "A"), Cells(a2, "AU")).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Selection.Paste

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know whichline gives the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find command giving error: “Run-time Error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26653203/11683)

Comment: the error shows at line a1=Findrow1.Row +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `Find` function, you need to confirm that `Find` was successful before assigning another variable to it's result.

Try the code scection below after you try to use `Find` 3 times:

```
' make sure Find was able to find all 3 strings
If Not FindRow1 Is Nothing And Not FindRow2 Is Nothing And FindRow3 Is Nothing Then
    a1 = FindRow1.Row + 1
    a2 = FindRow2.Row - 1
    b1 = FindRow2.Row + 1
    b2 = FindRow3.Row - 1
    c1 = FindRow3.Row + 1

    ' Copy >> Paste in 1 line (without using Select)
    Range(Cells(a1, "A"), Cells(a2, "AU")).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
Else ' FInd failed in at least one of the strings
    MsgBox "Find couldn't find at least one of the strings", vbCritical
End If
```

Comment: It works! Thank you for your answer. I think I missed the If Not part.

Comment: @D.D you're welcome, now comes your part where you mark this as "ANSWER", by clicking the gray check0mark on the left side of my answer (it will turn green), thanks

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to modify a bit to open file automatic but got an issue again which I don't understand why, can you help me check on this?

Comment: I use: Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim ba As String
Dim c As String
Dim ca As String

a = [LinkFolder]
b = [OpenF1]
ba = [nameF1]
c = [OpenF2]
ca = [nameF2]
=> to clarify the link to new worksheet, then try to copy: Range(Cells(a1, "A"), Cells(a2, "AU")).Copy Destination:=Workbooks(ca).Sheets("EUR-today").Range("A6") ---- but it doesn't work with the workbooks(ca) impression

Comment: @D.D Sounds like a new SO post, open a new post, add your modified code, and describe your error and what you are trying to achieve, it will allow other users (and me) to assist you. OK?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to VBA and also new to this forum. And I'm not an English native speaker so my question would be very difficult to follow. Thank you for your advise.
However I solved the problem. Will take your advise next time. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

use `selection.pastespecial` instead of `selection.paste`

or better yet, do not use `selection` at all, and instead, qualify your ranges properly.